# Escape out of nested loop in Python

Tags: python

I have the below code running in Python 2.7x:

```
def captureAlbumLinks():
    for page in index_pages: # index_pages is a list of URLs
        resp = connect_tor(page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read(), from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))
        try:
            # The below two variables relate to URLs of type string
            x = pickle.load(open("last_passworded_album.p", "rb"))
            y = pickle.load(open("last_accessible_album.p", "rb"))
        except:
            print "There is no pickle file"
        for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
            if (root_url + a['href']) == x or (root_url) + a['href'] == y:
                break
            elif "passchk.php" in a['href']:
                passworded_albums.append(root_url + a['href'])
            elif "search.php" in a['href'] or "switch.php" in a['href']:
                pass
            else:
                if ".html" in a['href']:
                    accessible_albums.append(root_url + a['href'])
```

In essence, "if (root_url + a['href']) == x or (root_url) + a['href'] == y:", I don't want any of the elifs to run and want to escape out of the '**for**' loop. Nonetheless, even when there is the if statement runs true (verified with a print statement), my code seems to run onto the next 'elif'. I think at the moment I'm just breaking from the 'if' loop and not the 'for' loop.

I feel this is an indentation problem but have tried moving the 'break' but with no joy.

Can anybody help?

Comment: it goes to the elif because your if never evaluates to True, what are x and y? i would also suggest printing `root_url + a['href'])`

Comment: You say "nested loops", I only see one... `break` has no interaction with `if` statements, if that block runs, if will break out of that `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks Padraic. X and Y are in essence URLs that will match the string formed by "root_url" + a['href']

Comment: Thanks Nick.  So how can I break out of the entire for loop if the IF returns true?

Comment: @thefragileomen, do you have this in a function?

Comment: Yes padraic. Shall I edit question with full function?

Comment: I don't see why you would have nested loops but if you have use return instead of break, that will end the function, if you have something else being executed in that function after maybe putting the loop code in an independent function would be a better idea. If you add the full code it will be easier.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks padraic. I've edited my original question to show the entire function.

Comment: Do you want the function to end if the first if statement is True or move to the next `index` in the outer loop?

Comment: Yes. If root_url == .... , (line 12) then I want the function to end

Comment: Then simply use `return`, also If you have an exception in that try block x and y won't be defined, you should also catch a specific error or errors, a blind except is never a good idea

Comment: @thefragileomen, I added an answer with a few more changes made.

Comment: **Never** you a plain `except`. If you want to check only if the file exists you should use `OSError`, or, in current python versions, use `FileNotFoundError` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply return to end the function:

```
import pickle
def capture_album_links():
    for page in index_pages: # index_pages is a list of URLs
        resp = connect_tor(page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read(), from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))
        try:
            # with will automatically close your files
            with open("last_passworded_album.p", "rb") as f1, open("last_accessible_album.p", "rb") as f2:
                x = pickle.load(f1)
                y = pickle.load(f2)
        # catch specific errors
        except (pickle.UnpicklingError,IOError) as e:
            print(e)
            print "There is no pickle file"
            # continue on error or x and y won't be defined 
            continue 
        for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
            if root_url + a['href'] in {x, y}:
                return # just return to end both loops
            elif "passchk.php" in a['href']:
                passworded_albums.append(root_url + a['href'])
            elif "search.php" in a['href'] or "switch.php" in a['href']:
                continue 
            else:
                if ".html" in a['href']:
                    accessible_albums.append(root_url + a['href'])
```

Answer (score 1):

A sometimes practical approach is to wrap it in a function and return. In your case you could just "return" but in general you'd write an inner function (in this case 'loops')

```
def captureAlbumLinks():
  def loops():
    for page in index_pages: # index_pages is a list of URLs
        resp = connect_tor(page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read(), from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))
        try:
            # The below two variables relate to URLs of type string
            x = pickle.load(open("last_passworded_album.p", "rb"))
            y = pickle.load(open("last_accessible_album.p", "rb"))
        except:
            print "There is no pickle file"
        for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
            if (root_url + a['href']) == x or (root_url) + a['href'] == y:
                return
            elif "passchk.php" in a['href']:
                passworded_albums.append(root_url + a['href'])
            elif "search.php" in a['href'] or "switch.php" in a['href']:
                pass
            else:
                if ".html" in a['href']:
                    accessible_albums.append(root_url + a['href'])
  return loops()
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the refactor into a function and return. You could also place the code in a try/except block and raise an exception when you want to break out off all the loops.

Answer (score 0):

edit: Suppressed useless comment. Adding alternatives:

Besides using return, in cases where you want to do something after the loop you can either use an exception:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def captureAlbumLinks():
    try:
        for page in index_pages: # index_pages is a list of URLs
            resp = connect_tor(page)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read(), from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))
            try:
                # The below two variables relate to URLs of type string
                x = pickle.load(open("last_passworded_album.p", "rb"))
                y = pickle.load(open("last_accessible_album.p", "rb"))
            except:
                print "There is no pickle file"
            for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
                if (root_url + a['href']) == x or (root_url + a['href']) == y:
                    raise MyException()
                elif "passchk.php" in a['href']:
                    passworded_albums.append(root_url + a['href'])
                elif "search.php" in a['href'] or "switch.php" in a['href']:
                    pass
                else:
                    if ".html" in a['href']:
                        accessible_albums.append(root_url + a['href'])
    except MyException as e:
        pass
```

Another approach, which might be less intuitive, is to use the `else` clause in `for` loops, which is executed only if the `for` stops normally (and not if you `break` out of it):

```
def captureAlbumLinks():
    for page in index_pages: # index_pages is a list of URLs
        resp = connect_tor(page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read(), from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))
        try:
            # The below two variables relate to URLs of type string
            x = pickle.load(open("last_passworded_album.p", "rb"))
            y = pickle.load(open("last_accessible_album.p", "rb"))
        except:
            print "There is no pickle file"
        for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
            if (root_url + a['href']) == x or (root_url + a['href']) == y:
                break
            elif "passchk.php" in a['href']:
                passworded_albums.append(root_url + a['href'])
            elif "search.php" in a['href'] or "switch.php" in a['href']:
                pass
            else:
                if ".html" in a['href']:
                    accessible_albums.append(root_url + a['href'])
        else:
            continue
        break
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. `break` is the correct solution if the author wants to get out of the loop (`return` as suggested in the comment above is overkill), so I'm trying to ask whether the issue doesn't come out of the test itself.
(Commenting is not possible since I've not yet enough karma.)

Comment: how is break going to break the outer loop? The parens also make no difference

Comment: Ah, when I wrote my first message there was just one loop (I'm slow to write, apparently), now it's clear indeed, sorry.
However, I believe a user exception would be slightly more general than simply returning.

Comment: If the OP wants to end the function a return is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Sure, but usually, you do something with what you did in the loop (and not rely as in here on side effects) and/or you want to do some cleanup. Knowing that using an exception is another way is interesting.

Comment: It is not a side effect, it is simply looping until a certain condition.

Comment: The downvote is probably because this reads like a clarifying question, which should be a comment. I know you didn't have enough rep to comment until this post got an upvote, but not having the rep to take the correct action isn't a good reason to knowingly take a wrong action. If you intended this to be an answer, you should reword it so it's very clearly an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I changed my answer so that it's useful. @Padraic: I meant that this whole function is useful only because of the side effect of changing the `passworded_albums` and `accessible_albums` lists. Without this side effect, the `return` statement would probably contain something useful and then, it might be easier to maintain if you stick to a single point of exit... hence breaking out of the loop in another way than a `return`.